# Why Python shell shows 'NameError: name 'inputwhichpower' is not defined. Did you mean: 'inputwhichpet'?'

Tags: python, error-handling

I am making a text adventure game while i get stuck in **'NameError: name 'inputwhichpower' is not defined. Did you mean: 'inputwhichpet'?'** inputwhichpower and inputwhichpet is a input. I have no idea what is causing the problem and how to fix it. my code is so big, so i am just uploading the code where the problem is facing on.

```
if inputcattype=="fire":
    inputwhichpower = input("Choose a power. [Fire Balls]")

if inputwhichpower=="fire balls":
    print("Fire balls come out of nowhere and hit Slenderbot.")
    print("It took 3 Damage. It died.")
```

Comment: The variable `inputwhichpower` will not be created if `inputcattype` is not `"Fire"`. That will be a problem in the `if/elif` below.

Comment: This is because `inputwhichpower` is defined only if ` inputcattype=="Fire"`. So, if `inputcattype` isn't equal to "Fire", you won't have such a variable (`inputwhichpower`), and you'll get NameError in the subsequent lines.

Comment: oh thanks. it is set to 'fire' not 'Fire'. so let me try adding a elif and check if it works

Comment: Heres what i got in the shell : 
You tamed the cat. Which type of power you wanna give your cat? fire
NameError: name 'inputwhichpower' is not defined. Did you mean: 'inputwhichpet'?

Comment: Please update the text of your question with your new code, the transcript from the above comment and the full error traceback.

Comment: New Code : 
```
elif inputcattype=="fire":
    print("You choose Fire power for your cat. It can do powers like 'Fire Balls'. if your cat evolve, it can do powers like 'Fire Hell'.")
if inputwhichpower=="fire balls":
    print("Fire balls come out of nowhere and hit Slenderbot.")
    print("It took 3 Damage. It died.")
```
Error:
NameError: name 'inputwhichpower' is not defined. Did you mean: 'inputwhichpet'?

Comment: No, sorry, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74155908/edit) you question with the full code, transcript and error traceback.

Comment: Either ensure that `inputwhichpower` is defined no matter what value `inputcattype` has, or ensure that `inputwhichpower` is only used when `inputcattype == "Fire"`.

Comment: inputwhichpower is only used after inputcattype == "fire"

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `inputwhichpower` is out of the second if statement's scope.

Here's the solution, you jsut have to specifiy that there IS a variable like that:

```
inputwhichpower = "";
if inputcattype=="fire":
    inputwhichpower = input("Choose a power. [Fire Balls]")

if inputwhichpower=="fire balls":
    print("Fire balls come out of nowhere and hit Slenderbot.")
    print("It took 3 Damage. It died.")
```